# Increase memory limit of a running pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3

I have a pod running in openshift 3.11, I wish to increase the pod memory limit from 2GB to 4GB. How to do it via Openshift Web Console or via OC command line?

When I try to edit the yaml file in Openshift Web Console  I got the following exception

> Reason: Pod "hjaha" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not
> change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`,
> `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or
> `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically Pods are deployed using containers template of the controllers of the Pods, such as DeploymentConfig, Deployment, DaemonSet, StatefulSet and so on. First of all, you should verify what controller is used for your Pod deployment and modify the resources section on the controller yaml, not running Pod yaml. Look at the following example, if you modify the memory limit on the deployment controller yaml using oc CLI or web console, then it will deploy new pod with new configuration after that.

```
// List some deployment controller resources as follows.
// Then you can see one which is similar name with running pod name.
$ oc get deploymentconfig,deployment,statefulset,daemonset -n <your project name>

$ oc edit <deployment controller type> <the resource name>
:
kind: <deployment controller type>
metadata:
  name: <the resource name>
spec:
  :
  template:
    :
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: <the container name>
          resources:
            limits:
              // modify the memory size from 2Gi to 4Gi.
              memory: 4Gi
```

Comment: Specifically, in my case I need to modify the deployment - I can't really do it at pod level as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the yaml file and add this `resources` section under your containers part

```
containers:
- image: nginx
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  name: default-mem-demo-ctr
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 4Gi  #<--------------This is limit
    requests:
      memory: 2Gi #<--------------Your applictaion will use memory in between 2Gb to upto 4GB
```

Comment: I have updated my questions to highlight an error when I used your approach, it looks like I can't update a running pod?

Comment: @william007 you can edtt it locally and replace that yaml file from local using command ```oc replace -f yourfile.yaml -n <your namespace>```

Comment: What is the namespace?

Comment: @william007 your openshift project name

Comment: Hmm..But I am going to only change the pod, not entire project

Comment: @william007 yes I know this will ensure you will apply thta yaml to that perticauler project

Comment: @william007 and it is always best practice while applying yaml file to include the project name because sometime you will end up applying to other project.